# How can I plot a region parametrized by another region?

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions, implicit

I am trying to learn how to describe and plot a 2D-region for $x_1$ and $x_2$ based on / parametrized by another 2D-region for $v_1$ and $v_2$.

In the following example, the region `vreg` for the variables `v1` and `v2` is described by the conditions `vcond` (in this simple example a circle). Now, for each point in `vreg`, I define some conditions for the variables `x1` and `x2` and with these conditions a region `xreg`.

At the end, I want to plot the region `xreg` by considering all points in `vreg` and generate points in this region. Unfortunately, however, the following code returns errors indicating that the region cannot be automatically discretized:

```
v = {v1, v2};
vcond = v1^2 + v2^2 <= 20;
vreg = ImplicitRegion[vcond, {v1, v2}];
f1low = 1 + v1*v2;
f1upp = 2 + 2*v1*v2 ;
f2low = 1 + v1*v2;
f2upp = 4 + 3*v1*v2;
xcond = f1low <= x1 <= f1upp && f2low <= x2 <= f2upp;
xreg = ImplicitRegion[xcond && Element[{v1, v2}, vreg], {x1, x2}]

RegionPlot@xreg
RandomPoint[xreg]
```

---

I know that I could begin generating points in `vreg` and try to evaluate all conditions with `Or`, e.g.,

```
vp = RandomPoint[vreg, 7];
xreg = ImplicitRegion[
  Simplify[Or @@ (xcond /. {v1 -> #[[1]], v2 -> #[[2]]} & /@ vp)], 
  {x1, x2}
]

 Show[
 {
  RegionPlot@xreg, 
  ParametricPlot[
    {{f1low, f2low}, {f1low, f2upp}, {f1upp, f2low}, {f1upp, f2upp}}, Element[{v1, v2}, vreg], 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ]
 }, 
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

But this is very time consuming and I need to take a look at the whole set.

Later, I also want to use more complicated conditions for `x1` and `x2`, e.g., `f[v1, v2] <= x1*x2` for nonlinear `f[v1, v2]` but first I want to understand this simpler problem.

**How can I plot the region `xreg`?**

Answer (score 3):

### Method-1

- `ParametricRegion` instead of `ImplicitRegion` make `RegionPlot` work.

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x1, x2}, 
    xcond && Element[{v1, v2}, vreg]}, {v1, v2, x1, x2}];
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]

- We can compare with `{f1low, f2low}, {f1low, f2upp}, {f1upp, f2low}, {f1upp, f2upp}` as show in the next picture.

```
Show[{RegionPlot@reg, 
  ParametricPlot[{{f1low, f2low}, {f1low, f2upp}, {f1upp, 
     f2low}, {f1upp, f2upp}}, Element[{v1, v2}, vreg], 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### Method-2

- `Exists`+ `Resolve`.

```
conditions = Exists[{v1, v2}, {v1, v2} ∈ vreg, xcond];
resolut = Resolve[conditions];
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[result, {x1, x2}]]
```

Or

```
conditions = 
 Exists[{v1, v2}, 
  v1^2 + v2^2 <= 20 && 1 + v1*v2 <= x1 <= 2 + 2 v1*v2 && 
   1 + v1*v2 <= x2 <= 4 + 3 v1*v2]
result = Resolve[conditions];
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[result, {x1, x2}]]
```

[image]